# Implementing fade-in / fade-out for a modal QDialog

Tags: qt

QDialog has a lot of functions to open and close, such as open(), show(), exec(),close(),hide(). I don't know which function to reimplement().

//edit:
  starting the animation in the showEvent() function is a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer: `void exec()`

long answer: `void exec()` BUT

you need to decide how you want the 'fade-in' work and to get how to use `QPropertyAnimation`

for example you could change opacity of the dialog:

```
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
int MyDialog::exec()
{
    this->setWindowOpacity(0.0);
    QPropertyAnimation* anim = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "windowOpacity");
    anim->setDuration(5000); // will take 5 seconds
    anim->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack); // just demonstration, there are a lot of curves to choose
    anim->setStartValue(0.0);
    anim->setEndValue(1.0);
    anim->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
    return QDialog::exec();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyDialog w;

    int ret = w.exec();
    return a.exec();
}
```

you can animate any `Property` defined by the `QObject`, everything else is playing with different animations and durations

edit: adapted to use `QDialog::exec()`, tested on Qt4.8.5, Vs2008, Win7Professionalx64
cheers

Comment: Note, that changing windowOpacity property doesn't work on all platforms.

Comment: auto myeffect=new QGraphicsOpacityEffect;
    this->setGraphicsEffect(myeffect);
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(myeffect,"opacity"); It is supposed to work fine. However, the dialog is black during the animation is running. @Zaiborg

Comment: Then it will not work if someone call  `show()` .Should I make 'show()' private ?

Comment: it should work in `show()` as well, you could overwrite all functions that should have the effect and refactor the code for animation into a single function and call it in every member when needed

Answer (score 0):

Overriding [QDialog::open](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) is the way to go. Unlike [QDialog::exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#open), it will return immediately on [QDialog::finished](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#finished) being called. Also, documentation advises against using exec.

[image]

The code below works nicely.

```
class AnimatedDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AnimatedDialog(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    void animate(bool reverse = false);

    void done(int r) override;
    void open() override;

signals:
    void reverseAnimStarted();

private:
    bool animation_on = false;
};


AnimatedDialog::AnimatedDialog(QWidget* parent) : QDialog{parent}
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Popup | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); 

    connect(this, &AnimatedDialog::reverseAnimStarted,
        [this] {animation_on = true; });
}

// override showEvent if you call show instead
void AnimatedDialog::open()
{
    animate(false);
    QDialog::open();
}

void AnimatedDialog::done(int r)
{
    if (!animation_on) {
        animate(true);
        setResult(r);
        if (r == QDialog::Accepted)
            emit accepted();
        else if (r == QDialog::Rejected)
            emit rejected();

        emit finished(r);
    }
}

void AnimatedDialog::animate(bool reverse)
{

    auto animFade= new QPropertyAnimation(this, "windowOpacity", this);
    animFade->setDuration(400);
    animFade->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);

    auto pos1 = QPoint{ (parentWidget()->pos().x() + parentWidget()->width() / 2 - width() / 2) + 15,
        (parentWidget()->pos().y() + parentWidget()->height() + height() / 2) / 2 };

    auto pos2 = QPoint{ (parentWidget()->pos().x() + parentWidget()->width() / 2 - width() / 2) + 15,
        (parentWidget()->pos().y() + parentWidget()->height() + height() / 2) / 2 - 65 };

    auto animMove = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "pos", this);
    animMove->setDuration(250);
    animMove->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutQuad);

    if (!reverse) {
        animFade->setStartValue(0.0);
        animFade->setEndValue(1.0);
        animMove->setStartValue(pos2);
        animMove->setEndValue(pos1);

    } else {
        emit reverseAnimStarted();
        animFade->setStartValue(1.0);
        animFade->setEndValue(0.0);
        animMove->setStartValue(pos1);
        animMove->setEndValue(pos2);

        connect(animFade, &QPropertyAnimation::finished,
            [this] { QDialog::hide(); });
    }

    animFade->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
    animMove->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}

void UI::viewDialog() {
    auto dialog = new AnimatedDialog{ this };
    dialog->open();

    connect(dialog, &AnimatedDialog::finished,
        [=] {}
    });

}
```